# Hibernate + Spring boot + PostgreSQL not auto Creating table on startup, no errors

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

I've started learning Springboot and I'm running into an issue when starting my application where Hibernate isn't creating a table from my entity. I'm using Postgres for SQL

I've also included the steps I have taken so far to try and troubleshoot. The application starts up, however it doesn't create my table

I'm not receiving any errors on startup.

**Entity class**

```
package com.example.springboot.student;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
@Table
public class Student {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "student_sequence",
            sequenceName = "student_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "student_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private LocalDate dob;
    private Integer age;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(Long id, String name, String email, LocalDate dob, Integer age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Student(String name, String email, LocalDate dob, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public LocalDate getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(LocalDate dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", dob=" + dob +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**main application Class**

```
package com.example.springboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
package com.example.springboot.student;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/student")
public class StudentController {

    private final StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return studentService.getStudents();
    }

}
```

**Service**

```
package com.example.springboot.student;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class StudentService {

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return List.of(
                new Student(
                        1L,
                        "Mariam",
                        "mariam.jamal@gmail.com",
                        LocalDate.of(2000, Month.JANUARY, 5),
                        21)
        );
    }

}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/student
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>clojars</id>
            <name>Clojars</name>
            <url>https://repo.clojars.org/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

**Console**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.9)

2023-03-09 06:30:19.292  INFO 14164 --- [           main] c.e.springboot.SpringbootApplication     : Starting SpringbootApplication using Java 11.0.17 on DESKTOP-RL97UQV with PID 14164 (D:\springboot\target\classes started by byoun in D:\springboot)
2023-03-09 06:30:19.294  INFO 14164 --- [           main] c.e.springboot.SpringbootApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-03-09 06:30:19.673  INFO 14164 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-03-09 06:30:19.679  INFO 14164 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 3 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2023-03-09 06:30:19.962  INFO 14164 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-03-09 06:30:19.968  INFO 14164 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-03-09 06:30:19.968  INFO 14164 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.71]
2023-03-09 06:30:20.047  INFO 14164 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-03-09 06:30:20.048  INFO 14164 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 717 ms
2023-03-09 06:30:20.318  INFO 14164 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-03-09 06:30:20.428  INFO 14164 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-03-09 06:30:20.514  INFO 14164 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-03-09 06:30:20.524  INFO 14164 --- [           main] c.e.springboot.SpringbootApplication     : Started SpringbootApplication in 1.507 seconds (JVM running for 2.216)
```

1. I changed my spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto from create-drop to just create
2. I've confirmed I have a successful connection to my DB from within my IDE
3. I updated the groupId and artifactId for my project package from the default that came from building the project with Spring initialzr
4. I have searched the depths of stack overflow and all of the recommendations to resolve issues appear to already be present in my code/files.
5. Included logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG to application.properties file but no logging is output from Hibernate

Comment: Please also show the package and annotations used in your main application class.

Comment: looks like You dont have configured repositories `Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 3 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.` add using `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation

Comment: @lukwas I'm wondering if part of the issue is that I don't have access to the annotation for Jpa only for Jdbc. I can use `@EnableJdbcRepositories` but I'm thinking that may not be what I need? I apologize I'm quite new to this. Perhaps I need a different dependency added? I did try it with `@EnableJdbcRepositories` but that had no affect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this setting to application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Please also change the part of pom.xml for use of JPA instead of JDBC.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thank you for the response! I did attempt adding this earlier and it did not resolve it, I added it back in one more time just to test and still the same result. You did ask for the packages in the main application class, I have added that code to the original post along with the other classes as it's a small application at this point so you can have full context.

Comment: Now I can see in your pom.xml that your application is set up for use of JDBC and for JPA. I would recommend the later. I have added the part to my original answer.

Comment: that did it! Thank you for very much for the help. I thought something was off when I saw JDBC instead of JPA. I actually did add that dependency at one point but I didn't reload Maven after changing it so it never updated my libraries.